# Finding a vertex that can be a root after some operations.

Tags: graph-theory

We are given a Tree with N verticies and directed edges. We can change their directions, so all edges will lead to the root. But every edge belongs to one of K groups. If you change the direction of one edge, then every edge which is in the same group will also change its direction. The task is to find the lowest number which can be made a root by changing directions of the edges. It is a programming task, so it has an input. In the first line we have two numbers - $N$ and $K$ $(1 \le N, K \le 10^5)$. In the next $N-1$ lines we have 3 numbers $a_i$, $b_i$ and $g_i$ $(1 \le a_i, b_i \le N; 1 \le g_i \le K)$, which means that $i$-th edge is directed from $a_i$ to $b_i$ and belongs to $g_i$ group. For example:

`5 1
4 3 1
2 1 1
1 4 1
1 5 1`

For this input, the right answer is 2.

Comment: It is possible to specify a system which cannot be solved: for example, switch `1 4 1` to read `4 1 1`. How should that situation be handled?

Comment: I forgot to say. There will be no situation like that. The input data are selected so there is always such a vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look for a group $g$ such that there exists a vertex $a$ that is twice on the same side of two edges *i.e.* for which there is the two lines
$a$ $b_i$ $g$ and $a$ $b_j$ $g$ or $b_i$ $a$ $g$ and $b_j$ $a$ $g$.

From this two lines you know that $b_j$ and $b_i$ must be below $a$ in the tree hence you change the the direction of the group if needed so that $b_i$ and $b_j$ point toward $a$ and mark the group $g$ so that it cannot change direction later.

Now, notice that in a marked group, all the vertex that appear left in the group $g$ cannot appear left again (there is only on father by vertex in the tree). Hence you can change the direction of all groups where one of this vertex appear and doing so mark this group. Notice also that those vertices cannot be the  root of the tree hence you can mark them.
If you are in a situation where on group should change direction and is already marked that mean there is no solution possible. Repeat this until all the possible group are marked.

Consider now the case where a vertex appear twice in a group but on two different sides *i.e.* where there are the two lines $a$ $b_j$ $g$ and $b_i$ $a$ $g$. From that you know that the father of $a$ is either $b_i$ or $b_j$ abd that it cannot be any other vertex. Thus you can change the direction of all the group in which $a$ appear left (except $g$) and mark all the group in which $a$ appear (except $g$ again). You can again repeat the previous paragraph to mark the maximum number groups. And you can mark $a$ as you are sure that it's not the root.

You are now in a situation where all the groups that have a determined direction are marked and all the vertex that cannot be the root are marked. to answer the question you only have to find the minimum of the non-marked vertices.